# '1 required argument(s) expected but 0 found' error

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying my hand at building an app with flutter (which uses Dart 2). I'm getting an error which I cant figure out:

The error is at the `child: new Center(`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Begin with a search...'),
        actions: <Widget> [
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('Logout', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: _signOut,
          )
        ]
      ),
      body: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                autofocus: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: 10.0),
                    child: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  ),
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                  hintText: 'Search for a recipient',
                ),
                onChanged: null,
              ),
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {_controller.clear();},
                child: new Icon(Icons.clear)
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavBar(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Do you get the same error when you run `flutter analyze` in the project directory? Can you please add the full error output?

Comment: Flutter version v0.5.1 (beta channel). Running `flutter analyze` does not return the same error. Only error there is `{
 "resource": "/Users/Samuel/Documents/GitHub/MyApp/lib/root_page.dart",
 "owner": "dart",
 "code": "missing_return",
 "severity": 4,
 "message": "This function declares a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.",
 "source": "dart",
 "startLineNumber": 47,
 "startColumn": 5,
 "endLineNumber": 47,
 "endColumn": 11,
 "tags": []
}`

Comment: Then perhaps restarting the IDE should already fix it. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Using VSCode. I just restarted and it worked! Thanks... such a simple solution haha

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: In my case I was trying to call a constructer with named parameter even though the parameter wasn't named the ctor needed an argument. Like this: wrong: `Icon(icon: Icons.ac_unit)`, correct: `Icon(Icons.ac_unit)`

Answer (score 13):

I had a terrible time with this error (apparently different root cause as that corrected via comments above.) . Info offered here in case anybody else finds this posting based on the error code.

In my case I had a poorly formed constructor...

in main.dart...

```
@override
  void initState() {
    tapScreen = PageTapScreen(
      key : keyOne,
      profileList :  demoProfiles,
      tapScreenContext : tapScreenContext,
    ); . . .
```

Elsewhere in my code base:

```
class PageTapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Key key;
  final List<Profile> profileList;
  final BuildContext tapScreenContext;  

PageTapScreen(
    this.key,
    this.profileList,
    this.tapScreenContext) : super(key: key)  . . .
```

Error generated from the `tapScreen = ...` call in main.dart:

```
3 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
The named parameter 'key' isn't defined.
The named parameter 'profileList' isn't defined.
The named parameter 'tapScreenContext' isn't defined.
```

The fix was to add curly brackets to the Class constructor to clearly specify named parameters, [per this reference.](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#optional-named-parameters)

```
PageTapScreen({
    this.key,
    this.profileList,
    this.tapScreenContext}) : super(key: key)
```

Again, the only reason I'm posting here is to highlight a potential fix to the error code noted in the original write up.  Thia fix may not be intuitive based on  the error message.

Answer (score 2):

There can be few reasons. I am adding my own foolish reason(.

**Error constructor**:

```
const SingleShiftModel(
      this.parentId,
      {this.id,
      this.siteName,
      this.startTime,
      this.endTime,
      this.isDay,
      this.breakTimeInMins,
      this.isSigned,
      this.hourlyRate,
      this.date,
      this.comment,
      this.pngSignatureBytes});
```

**What I changed and it worked? ->**

```
const SingleShiftModel(
      {this.parentId,
      this.id,
      this.siteName,
      this.startTime,
      this.endTime,
      this.isDay,
      this.breakTimeInMins,
      this.isSigned,
      this.hourlyRate,
      this.date,
      this.comment,
      this.pngSignatureBytes});
```

Thank you! Hope answered your question!

Answer (score 1):

I think you changed the Basic.dart widget unintentionally. In (your_flutter_sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart).
You need a new one. You need to re-install the Flutter package.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with the response. So i solved it like this

```
 @override
 Future<AuthUser> doLogin(data) async {
 final response = await http.post('$baseUrl/user/login', body: data);

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   var data = json.decode(response.body); 
    print(data['success']['user']);
    return AuthUser.fromJson(data['success']['user']); 
 }else {
   throw new Exception('Failed To Login User');
 }


}
```